Proving determinant equation using induction
How would I go about proving this determinant using induction?
$
\begin{align*}
\left|\begin{array}{ccccccc}
n & n-1 & \ldots & 4 & 3 & 2 & 1 \\
n & n-1 & \ldots & 4 & 3 & 3 & 1 \\
n & n-1 & \ldots & 4 & 5 & 2 & 1 \\
n & n-1 & \ldots & 7 & 3 & 2 & 1 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ldots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
2 n-1 & n-1 & \ldots & 4 & 3 & 2 & 1
\end{array}\right|=(-1)^{\frac{n(n-1)}{2}}(n-1) !
\end{align*}
$
The work I've tried: I showed that this equation is true by subtracting the first row from all the other rows and then using Laplace expansion on the last element of every column to calculate the determinant. Then I tried using $D_n$ to prove by induction but I just can't get it right. I got that $D_n = (-1)^{n-1}\cdot D_{n-1}$ and $D_{n-1} = (-1)^{n-1}\cdot D_{n-1}\cdot (-1)^{n-2}\cdot2\cdot D_{n-2}$. But plugging in values into this tells me I got it wrong. Im stuck as I don't know what steps I should take. All help appreciated.

Can you say what the pattern is for the entries of the matrix? It looks like it goes $n,\cdots,1$ in each row, except the antidiagonal is replaced with the odd numbers $1,3,5,\cdots$ starting from the upper right. Anyway, just subtract the second and last column from the first.

@coiso Yes, that is the pattern. For $D_{4}$ for example it would be \begin{equation*}
\begin{bmatrix}
4 & 3 & 2 & 1 \
4 & 3 & 3 & 1 \
4 & 5 & 2 & 1 \
7 & 3 & 2 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation*}
If I'm not mistaken.

@coiso I don't see what happens, sorry... I mean I see but don't understand how it is useful is what I mean.

@SammyBlack It is the exact same here as it is in our practice sheet, I just checked.

Whoops. I read it too quickly. I will delete my comment. Thanks, @coiso.

Let's work on the version of the matrix where you've subtracted the first row from all other rows. This yields:
$$
\begin{align*}
B(n) &=
\left[\begin{array}{cccccc}
n & \ldots & 4 & 3 & 2 & 1 \\
0 & \ldots & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & \ldots & 0 & 2 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & \ldots & 3 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 \vdots & \ldots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
n-1 & \ldots & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{array}\right]
\end{align*}
$$
Observe now that the product of the entries along the top-right to bottom-left diagonal are exactly $(n-1)!$. This matrix, however, is not quite lower triangular!
We need to rearrange the columns so that the entries below the main diagonal (top-left to bottom-right) are zero. This is where the extra factor of $(-1)^{\frac{n(n-1)}{2}}$ comes from.
Swapping the columns of $B(n)$ to obtain the matrix
$$
\begin{align*}
C(n) &=
\left[\begin{array}{cccccc}
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & \ldots & n \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 2 & 0 & \ldots & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 3 & \ldots & 0 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
0 & \ldots & 0 & 0 & 0 & n-1
\end{array}\right]
\end{align*}
$$
using "bubble sort" it takes $\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$ swaps.
That is, to sort the descending list $n, n-1, \dots, 1$ to the ascending list $1, 2, \dots, n$ can be done using $\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$ swaps.
Thus, it follows that the determinant of your matrix is $ (-1)^{\frac{n(n-1)}{2}}(n-1) !$

This is a great explanation on why the equality holds, I did not think of using bubble sort to rearrange the determinant! But it is not quite the proof by induction I'm looking for.

@TamirOladejo I suppose this is basically induction with just a base case :)) you could try proving the bubble sort complexity using induction if you want.
